# How to change background image

Tags: images, css, custom-background

I am new to wordpress and although searched all over I cannot seem to find an answer for my question so any help would be appreciated:

I have the following code:

```
[vc_row row_type="parallax" content_width="grid" full_screen_section_height="yes" vertically_align_content_in_middle="yes" parallax_background_image="2407"]
```

I need to change the `parallax_background_image="2407"` to another file.

I have already uploaded the new file in the Media library but cannot find how to reflect the change.

I assume I have to edit some css code but have no idea where to find the relevant code.

FYI: there are several of those background images on the same page that I want to edit, if this is at all important.

Any ideas?

Comment: This code isn't coming from Core, so you should search down where the shortcode comes from - a theme or a plugin. My guess is that "2407" might be the Post ID of a particular image. If that is true, then you can go into your Media Library and find the Post ID of the image you want, and paste that in instead of the 2407.

Comment: Thanks, mate! That helped a lot. Indeed the "2407" was the post ID of the image in question. I just changed it to the post ID of my image and it was changed! Thanks, you can post this as answer so that I can accept it as such!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code isn't coming from Core, so you should search down where the shortcode comes from - a theme or a plugin. My guess is that "2407" might be the Post ID of a particular image. If that is true, then you can go into your Media Library and find the Post ID of the image you want, and paste that in instead of the 2407.

Comment: Answer accepted. Apologies for addressing you as "mate" just saw your photo :)

Comment: lol, no worries :)